# GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: grails

I got the error below using Grails and Spring Security. Has anyone else had a problem like this? If so, what was your fix?

```
Error |
Exception in thread "Thread-15" 
Error |
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectWatcher.run(GrailsProjectWatcher.java:114)
```

And

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'User_name'
```

Comment: `grep` your code for `User_name` and show us the code surrounding it

Comment: "${my_var}".toString Works for me Thanks CyberAleks

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Did you generate all the classes (User, Role ...). 
How does your command looks like? 
Like this `grails s2-quickstart com.testapp User Role`?
Check your configuration and try it like in this tutorial.
[Spring Security Plugin Tutorials](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/tutorials.html)

Actually this error means in groovy that you use a GString like "${my_var}" and some class expects String. It can't be cast automatically. If you have some code like this, you have to convert it to String like this: `"${my_var}".toString()`.

Comment: In particular, if you try to assign a GString to something that is statically typed as String (or pass a GString for a String-type method parameter) then Groovy will do the conversion for you, but if you assign to something that is typed as Object then you have to convert it yourself.

Comment: Agree. I think the problem can be the code like def myvar = "${some value}" that will be delegate to some java classes in spring security framework.

Comment: This answer worked for me, but in my case, its use was in a `build.gradle` file.

Comment: FWIW, you can just `'' + "${my_var}"` (old String concat trick forcing `toString()` on the args, it will be optimized out by the compiler anyway)