# Artifactory in Jenkins pipeline: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have this in my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
stage('Artifactory Deploy') {
    options {
        timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES')
    }
    when {
        anyOf {
            branch "master"
            branch "develop"
        }
    }
    steps {
        withMaven(jdk: "${JDK_VERSION}", maven: 'M3') {
            script {
                def server = Artifactory.server('itext-artifactory')
                def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
                rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'releases', snapshotRepo: 'snapshot'
                rtMaven.tool = 'M3'
                def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml',
                        goals: "--threads 2C --no-transfer-progress " +
                                "install --activate-profiles artifactory " +
                                "-Dmaven.repo.local=${env.WORKSPACE.replace('\\','/')}/.repository"
                server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`${env.WORKSPACE.replace('\\','/')}` is required because while Linux behaves as expected, Windows apparently behaves like T̪̩͑̒̀o̭̦̱͎̗̲̎̿̎ͩ̓̏̔n̊̀ͅy̲͓̘ͥͬ̾ͮ̌ͮ̐ ̘̪̝̳̺̖t̪͎̒̓͑̆̎̚h̵ͥͯ̅ͯ̚ȩ̟̩̞̹̫̌ͦ̉͂ͨ̔ͣͅ ̺͋̆͂̅ͥP̵̖̞͕̲̂̄ͥͩơ̙͇̫̰͍ͮ̽̓nͨ̄ͮy̘̪ͨͯ͂ͪ with regards to path separators.

I'd much rather have

```
withMaven(jdk: "${JDK_VERSION}", maven: 'M3', mavenLocalRepo: '.repository')
```

but we can't have nice things.

Anyway, when running this on Jenkins, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.builds.MavenBuild.run(MavenBuild.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:193)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor290.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor340.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:107)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor290.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:89)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor290.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and no artifacts are deployed to Artifactory (and the build fails).

How to fix this? Either upstream bugfix or local workaround.

Posting my question on Stack Overflow because we have an Artifactory Pro license, and Jfrog's customer support portal is only available for Pro X, Enterprise and Enterprise+ customers. Other customers get directed to Stack Overflow, see https://jfrog.com/support/.

Answer (score 7):

A possible root cause is something found in a comment on [GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079574/gstringimpl-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-string#comment46394473_29080629):

> if you try to assign a `GString` to something that is statically typed as `String` (or pass a `GString` for a `String`-type method parameter) then Groovy will do the conversion for you, but if you assign to something that is typed as `Object` then you have to convert it yourself.

Because I'm using a variable in curly braces (`${env.WORKSPACE.replace('\\','/')}`), I automatically have a Groovy `GString` instead of a Java `String`.

So, Jfrog staff, if you are monitoring the `artifactory` tag on Stack Overflow: according to the [Jenkins documentation for the Artifactory plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/artifactory/#artifactorymavenbuild-run-artifactory-maven), `goals` is defined as type `String`, but apparently this is not the case because Groovy can't do the conversion? Can you confirm or explain? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I found the [Jenkins Artifactory Plugin API Javadocs](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/artifactory/) and [the `run()` method of `org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.builds.MavenBuild`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/artifactory/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/common/types/builds/MavenBuild.html#run-java.util.Map-) takes a `Map` as argument:

```
public void run(Map<String,Object> args)
```

So indeed, while Groovy will automagically do the conversion from a Groovy `GString` to a Java `String`, it won't do the conversion from a Groovy `Gstring` to an `Object` inside a `Map`.

**Workaround**

As described in the linked question, I added `.toString()` to manually convert the Groovy `GString` to a Java `String`.

So

```
def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml',
        goals: "--threads 2C --no-transfer-progress " +
                "install --activate-profiles artifactory " +
                "-Dmaven.repo.local=${env.WORKSPACE.replace('\\','/')}/.repository"
```

became

```
def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml',
        goals: "--threads 2C --no-transfer-progress " +
                "install --activate-profiles artifactory " +
                "-Dmaven.repo.local=${env.WORKSPACE.replace('\\','/')}/.repository".toString()
```